# How to convert data from mongodb document to List

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I Create a web-site and I have a problem. When I'm tring to get datas from mongodb and convert it to list, I have an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'CategoryModel'"

this is classes

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("title")]
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("slug")]
    public string slug { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("__v")]
    
    public int __v { get; set; }
}


public class ProductsModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
   
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("desc")]
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("price")]
    public int price { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("category")]
    public CategoryModel category { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("image")]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

this is my conntroller

```
 public class ProductsController:Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    List<CategoryModel> categoriesList = new List<CategoryModel>();
    List<ProductsModel> productsList = new List<ProductsModel>();

    
    [HttpGet("products")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Product()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("cmscart");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<CategoryModel>("categories");

        var result = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
           
            categoriesList.Add(new CategoryModel() { Name = (string)item["[title]"] }); //here I have an error
        }

        //products

        var client2 = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var database2 = client2.GetDatabase("cmscart");
        var collection2 = database2.GetCollection<ProductsModel>("products");

        var result2 = await collection2.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();


        

        foreach (var item2 in result2)
        {

           
            productsList.Add(new ProductsModel() { Name = (string)item2["title"], Desc = (string)item2["desc"], price = (int)item2["price"], ImageURL = (string)item2["image"] }); // and here I have an error
        }

        



        return View(categoryProduct);
        
    }
}
```

I found a lot of solutions but I don't understand why this error is appear, because if this trick do with SQL then I don't have this error

Comment: Please post a minimal example to illustrate the problem and show which line is causing the problem.

Comment: @Ian Mercer one moment

Comment: @Ian Mercer that's all, I edited

Comment: Why aren't you just using `item.Name`? It's a strongly-typed `CategoryModel` object, it has properties. What editor are you using that doesn't show these properties when you hit `.`?

Comment: @Ian Mercer I'm using VS (not code). Through `.` , is it how? Because I don't understand, i'm junior and don't understand how to do it through `.`

Comment: `item` is an object of type `CategoryModel`. To access the property `Name` just use `item.Name`. In JSON and BSON you have chosen to serialize that property as `title`. Not sure why you don't call it `Title` in C#, but you didn't. You are mixing accessing json properties and C# properties. MongoDB has already converted the object for you into the C# class.

Comment: @Ian Mercer 
Can you write what the request itself looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the deserialized object directly:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
var database = client.GetDatabase("cmscart");
var collection = database.GetCollection<CategoryModel>("categories");

List<CategoryModel> categoriesList = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

//products

var collection2 = database2.GetCollection<ProductsModel>("products");
List<ProductsModel> products = await collection2.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

Also, don't use class properties for local variables, declare everything in the innermost scope possible (in general). Ideally the `MongoClient` or `Database` would be injected into the class constructor too. You don't want to be instantiating them in an action method and you definitely don't want configuration values in there.

Comment: But I have another problem elso which appear now. It `Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a WebApplication3.Models.CategoryModel value, but found a value of type String instead`. I thisnk that is tying with field `category` in `ProductsModel`

Comment: @Key perhaps some older data in the database when category was serialized as a string? Use Mongo shell to browse the data and see what's there in the category field.